# Create multiple instances of components in Meteor JS

Tags: templates, meteor, meteor-blaze, multiple-instances

I am creating the elements like button, textfield, select as components in different templates. How do I  create multiples of an instance of this components on a form (template) in my project? An example is using multiple textfields on a page.

Let's say I want to create a signup page and I'll need 3 textfields, 2 buttons, how do create them?

This is a sample:

```
<template name="mybutton">
    <input type="button" name="{{butonname}}" class="{{buttonclass}}" placeholder="{{buttonplaceholder}}">
</template>

<template name="mytext">
    <input type="text" name="{{textname}}" class="{{textclass}}" placeholder="{{textplaceholder}}">
</template>

<template name="signup">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getTemplateName }}
</template>

Template.signup.onCreated(funtion(){
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    this.state.set('targetTemplate', 'mybutton');
})

Template.sidebar.helpers({
    getTemplateName(){
        return Template.instance().state.get("targetTemplate");
    }
})
```

Comment: What is the reason for using `Template.dynamic` instead of directly calling your template?

Comment: I am loading different templates at run-time in the same frame. To have loaded all the template would defeat the purpose of the re-usability I want to achieve.

Comment: You should describe your constraints, otherwise potential answers would not meet them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you intend to do, but if I get it right, you want to render more than one dynamic template inside a template!?

If so, then you also need more than one dynamic Reactive data source:

```
<template name="signup">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getPrimaryTemplate }}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=getSecondaryTemplate }}
</template>


Template.signup.onCreated(function(){
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    this.state.set('primaryTemplate', 'mybutton');
    this.state.set('secondaryTemplate', 'myText');
})

Template.sidebar.helpers({
    getPrimaryTemplate(){
        return Template.instance().state.get("primaryTemplate");
    },
    getSecondaryTemplate(){
        return Template.instance().state.get("secondaryTemplate");
    },
});
```

**More generic approach:** If you have to deal with many dynamic templates you can also wrap this into a single helper:

```
<template name="signup">
    {{> Template.dynamic template=(getTemplate 'header') }}

    {{> Template.dynamic template=(getTemplate 'body') }}

    {{> Template.dynamic template=(getTemplate 'footer') }}
</template>


Template.signup.onCreated(function(){
    this.state = new ReactiveDict();
    this.state.set('header', 'mybutton');
    this.state.set('body', 'myText');
    this.state.set('footer', 'someOtherTemplate');
})

Template.sidebar.helpers({
    getTemplate(templateName) {
        return Template.instance().state.get(templateName);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In blaze you can just include a template as many times as you want - I'm not sure what you're looking for beyond this - your question is not exactly clear.

```
{{> mytext }}
{{> mybutton }}
{{> mytext }}
{{> mytext }}
{{> mybutton }}
```